# loading separate css stylesheet (heroku nodejs)

Tags: css, node.js, heroku

I am unable to load a separate css stylesheet for a heroku web app, both locally and on heroku server. I recently migrated over from google app engine and the way I loaded stylesheets there worked perfectly fine. What am I doing wrong here?? Any help would be greatly appreciated!! Here is my code:

/app/server.js

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
app.use(express.logger());

var fs = require("fs");
var buf = fs.readFileSync("html/index.html");
var index = buf.toString();

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    response.send(index);
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log("Listening on " + port);
});
```

/app/html/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Starters Singapore | Social Group Dating</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/index.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="testdiv">This is a test</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

/app/css/index.css

```
body{
    margin:0;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #666666;
}

#testdiv{
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    background-color: #00a1ec;
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more detailed your problem? I cannot get it.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a relative path to the css file. This path is relative to the server root and not to the html file. I have no experience with Heroku NodeJS but I think the path should be

> /css/index.css

Answer (score 0):

I deploy apps on Heroku as well. I would suggest using ejs or jade to render your html. I prefer ejs. Since you're using Express, I would also create a "public" directory using [this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10644431/default-folder-functionality-for-node-js). 
[image]

Then in your **layout.ejs** (for Express 2.x.x or Express 3.x.x using ejs-locals npm)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>The Title</title>
    <% stylesheet('/css/index.css') %>
    <%- stylesheets%>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

You would also have an **index.ejs** where you call this layout.ejs

```
<%- layout('layout') %>
```

I would also suggest referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11751114/layout-ejs-doesnt-work-on-nodejs-app-in-heroku) when using layouts with ejs. Learning ejs or jade might be slightly slightly annoying at first, but it works great once you understand it better. Hopefully this isn't too much of a loaded answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what helped me:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/')); //use static dirname
```

Assuming that you have everything placed in your root folder. For example I have css files placed inside a folder name css(which is inside root folder*). Then I can use `./css/bootstrap.min.css` inside of my index.html file (which is also in the root folder as a neighbor to the css folder).

*root folder here refers to the project root folder.